# Custom Hot keys in Unity editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I want to change my shading mode with custom hot key. Is there any kind of way to set your custom hot keys, in unity editor 2022.3f LTS?

I have tried to find out the way. How, we can make our custom hotkeys? But, I can't get the option in unity editor. Can, anybody help me out?

Comment: Search "render mode"

Answer (score 1):

you can write an script and add a menu item to do it and in definition you can define its hotkey for example following code will open one of my scenes when I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>.

the part that is `%#&m` defines its shortcut. see [unity document](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html)

> To create a hotkey, use the following special characters:
> %: Represents Ctrl on Windows and Linux. Cmd on macOS.
> ^: Represents Ctrl on Windows, Linux, and macOS.
> #: Represents Shift.
> &: Represents Alt.

```cs
[MenuItem("Tools/Scenes/Main %#&m")]
public static void OpenMain()
{
if (EditorSceneManager.SaveCurrentModifiedScenesIfUserWantsTo())
      EditorSceneManager.OpenScene(Application.dataPath +"/Scenes/Main.unity");
}
```